# EntityFramework Nested Objects Update

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

What is so wrong about the below that the nested object never updates?

```
[Route("api/branches/{id}/devices")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PutDevice(int id, Device device)
{
    Branch branch = await  db.Branches.Include("devices").FirstAsync(b => b.id == id);
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
    if (branch == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    device.branch = branch;

    try
    {
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
        if (!BranchExists(id))
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
}
```

I'm just passing a device object, and the branch ID. All i'm trying to do is to update a device's branch... However, the value never changes.

What am I missing?

## Device.cs

```
public class Device
{
    public Device()
    {
        date_created = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }

    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
  
    public string name { get; set; }
    
    public virtual Branch branch { get; set; }

    public int branch_id { get; set; }
```

Comment: Isn't `Device` just a view model here? I don't see where is a tracked entity...

Comment: @RonBeyer please check the edit.

Comment: I see it,  but how does it get into the controller? If it's loaded from the view is acting as a view model, what happens when you load another tracked entity using the Id from the device, assign its branch,  then save it? I'm guessing the passed in entity isn't being tracked.

Comment: What do you mean, `device` is there with all of its properties. It's passed via POST (from angularjs)

Comment: The device state is unchanged and you should set its state to modified and then save it.

Comment: `db.Entry(device).State = EntityState.Modified;`

Comment: @RezaAghaei Same, I've tried it. Doesn't update.

Comment: **1-** Doesn't update or throws an exception? **2-** Do you have any `BranchId` field in `Device`?

Comment: why you don't add the device to the list of devices in Branch entity and try to save the entity ? I assume that Branch has a list or collection of devices. Or you add branchId in device entity and set that property before saving the entity.

Comment: @RezaAghaei It doesn't update. 
            device.branch = branch;
            db.Entry(device).State = EntityState.Modified; - Also I have this in device.cs -> 
        public int branch_id { get; set; }

Comment: So you can simply set the `device.branch_id=id;` and then if device is an edited entity set `db.Entry(device).State = EntityState.Modified;` else if the device is a new entity set `db.Entry(device).State = EntityState.Added;` (or db.Devices.Add(device);) and at last `db.SaveChanges();` you even don't need to load branch.

Comment: well, you have loaded the branch but then saved the device, which is not tracked ! if device was a new entity, you need to add it to the list of devices after you set the branch Id property and then save it.

Comment: @Omar.Alani Device here is never a new entity, I just need to update the relationship so that this device is tied to the branch I loaded...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You received the `device` from post values and it is not tracked by context. So when you call `db.SaveChanges` the context doesn't see any changes.

As you mentioned in comments, you have `branch_id` in `device` class, you can set the `id` to `branch_id` and you don't need to perform a query to load a branch at all.

To add a new device:

```
device.branch_id = id;   
db.Devices.Add(device);
db.SaveChanges();
```

To edit an existing device:

```
device.branch_id = id;   
db.Entry(device).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But `device` is most likely always in the database, I just want to update the relationship.. Not add it again.

Comment: No difference, the main part of the answer is the first two lines. I'll eidt the answer for update entity.

Comment: Thanks again, one more thing to note is that branch_id for device can be optional. Does this matter? Meaning we can have a device without a branch at any given time.

Comment: It only changes the signature of your action, but doesn't changes EF concepts, So your action signature should be `(int? id, Device device)` instead.

Comment: @user1027620 Thank you for your feedback

Comment: It worked for me: I was not expecting it to add a new nested object into its respective table in my database with a brand-new Id automatically - the modified state is what ensures the entry is really changed in-place.

Answer (score 2):

Your variable device isn't in EF context, so EF doesnt know about it, and he will never change the device.

You can try something like this:

```cs
[Route("api/branches/{id}/devices")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PutDevice(int id, Device device)
{
    Branch branch = await  db.Branches.Include("devices").FirstAsync(b => b.id == id);
    Device dbDevice = await  db.Devices.Find(device.id);
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
    if (branch == null || dbDevice == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    dbDevice.branch = branch;

    try
    {
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
        if (!BranchExists(id))
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
}
```

Comment: You don't need a round trip to server to find the original device, only `db.Entry(device).State = EntityState.Modified;` is enough.

Comment: Also since `device` has a `branch_id`, again we don't need a round trip to server to find any branch, it's enough to set the `device.branch_id`

Comment: @RezaAghaei I know that, but you said that to him, and he said that tried that, and didnt worked.

Comment: @RezaAghaei if you look again in her Device class, you will not set branch_id property.

Comment: Probably it's the OP mistake. IMHO we should not lead him to an incorrect way. Also `branch_id` is mentioned in [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34080124/entityframework-nested-objects-update#comment55913858_34080124).

Comment: @RezaAghaei Why is this a incorrect way? I will agree with you if you say that is not the best, but it is not incorrect. But at first you tried teaching the best way, he said that didnt worked, so lets try to make it work, and then we can figure out best way to provide a code refactor to make it better.

Comment: Not struggling, It's not the wrong way, technically you are right, but it has 2 more request to server that is so bad :)

Comment: Never mind, You are trying to help the OP, and it is precious. That's it :)

Comment: Both solutions work.. Don't know which one to tick as an answer :P

Comment: Btw ended up doing this -> 
            Device _device = await db.Devices.FindAsync(device.id);
            _device.branch_id = id;
            _device.branch = await db.Branches.FindAsync(id);
            db.Entry(_device).State = EntityState.Modified;

Comment: Only reason is that I need the API to return the branches object when GET all devices... Just updating the ID didn't do it at first had to add this -> _device.branch = await db.Branches.FindAsync(id); and in the GET devices I added .Include("branch");

Comment: @user1027620 While you can accept only one answer, you can vote for as many answers as you find helpful, including the accepted one:)

Comment: user1027620 pick the @rezaaghei

Comment: @AlbertoMonteiro Thanks alot, upvoted your answer and it works. Marked the other response as answer because I tried that solution first.

Comment: I just wanted to help, and i am happy that you solved the problem!!

Comment: @AlbertoMonteiro Thank you for trying to help other users +1 to your answer :)

Comment: Its my pleasure @RezaAghaei :D
Thank you too to help them!!